# Animating Menu icon like google apps

Tags: android, animation, icons, slidingmenu

Im trying to achieve the neat menu icon ui like in all the new google apps, 
im talking about the "hotdog" menu icon that animates when it is pressed, sliding a bit to the left when the sliding menu slides to the right.

Im using the android SlidingMenu library btw.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Modify library code, or ask author to add this feature.

Comment: If you don't mind to change the library `SherlockNavigationDrawer` does that animation: https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using ABS... read this: http://jakewharton.com/deprecated-from-inception/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that SlidingMenu library wont do it...

if anyone else is looking for an answer i am recommending to use the native library: NavigationDrawer, here's a tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Enjoy :)